# Comparing and extracting data from CSV file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a `csv1` file with data:

[image]

I have a `csv2` file with data:

[image]

Now I want to extract data from `csv2` file which has data in common with `csv1` file. For example `csv1` first line `raghu@xyz.com` and sales should compare with lines in `csv2` if the line matches I have to get the data from `csv2` file like `raghu@xyz.com,sales,chennai` and `shekar@xyz.com,Marketing,Bangalore`. Hope you understood my question. Please help me to write a powershell script for this one.

Comment: PLEASE ... do not post images of data/errors/code. why? lookee ... Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Given the identical column names, you can use `Compare-Object` to extract the rows from the second CSV where a matching row exists in the first CSV:

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv path\to\first_file.csv
$csv2 = Import-Csv path\to\second_file.csv

Compare-Object $csv2 $csv1 -Property EmailID,Department -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru |Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator
```

- `-Property EmailID,Department` ensures that `Compare-Object` compares both of those properties on all input objects.
- `-IncludeEqual`, `-ExcludeDifferent` ensure we get the rows from CSV 2 that *matches* some row from CSV 1 rather than those that are different.
- `-PassThru` gives us the original input objects from `$csv2`
- Piping to `Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator` removes the `SideIndicator` property attached by `Compare-Object`